# Using Javascript to alter specific section of css animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation

I'm trying to use javascript to alter the 50% section of this css..

```
@keyframes shake1 {
0% { transform: translate(0px); visibility: hidden; }
1% { visibility: visible;}
50% { transform: translate(0.7px);}
100% { transform: translate(0px); }
}
```

.. using something like this (sorry this is a complete guess of what it might look like)..

```
document.getElementById('@keyframes shake1').style.50%  = "0.6"px;
```

.. to be able to change the translate to different values (0, 0.1, 0.2 etc) in response to what time it is, like this, for example..

```
<script>

var currentTime = new Date().getHours();

if (0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12) 
{
document.getElementById('@keyframes shake1').style.50%  = "0.1"px;
}

else if (12 <= currentTime && currentTime < 24) 
{
document.getElementById('@keyframes shake1').style.50%  = "0.4"px;
}

</script>
```

Just looking for the specific javascript phrase to target that specific section of the css animation?

Thanks !

Comment: You could just use different classes? I mean wouldn't that be the easiest option? FYI. ```getElementById('@keyframes shake1')``` wouldn't work because you wouldn't have ```@keyframes``` as a part of the ID?

Comment: Yeah, just make another keyframes definition, and then break early for the weekend.

Comment: hey just edited my question to show where this is heading, sorry it wasn't so clear before !

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it is possible (though poorly supported by browsers) to access this through the [CSSKeyframesRule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSKeyframesRule) interface.

It will likely be much simpler, however, to simply define another named [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and use JavaScript to apply each separate animation with a different class.

In your CSS stylesheet:

```
@keyframes shake1 {...}
@keyframes shake2 {...}

.morning {
  /* use shake1 in an animation */
}

.afternoon {
  /* use shake2 in an animation */
}
```

In your script:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
var someElement = document.getElementById('#some-id');

if (0 <= currentTime && currentTime < 12) {
  someElement.classList.add('morning');
}
else if (12 <= currentTime && currentTime < 24) {
  someElement.classList.add('afternoon');
}
```

Comment: hey Morgan, just started to integrate this into my site, but realising I might need to use the CSSKeyframesRule, because for example every letter in these constellations has a different speed applied, and a different delay, so a lot easier to try and target the animation itself. If you view the source here.. http://sarahboulton.co.uk/chapelbedroom.html . How would you approach it with the CSSKeyframesRule ? Thanks !

Comment: To be honest, we're going really far off the beaten path here, so I'm not entirely sure. My intuition is that there might be a better way to do this than using keyframes, but here's a keyframe example for now (not mine). https://codepen.io/estelle/pen/dogmoG. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?